# [Navigation] Is there a ROS Framework to integrate arbitrary local and global planners?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a simple solution to integrate any arbitrary local and global planner in ROS without a lot of hassles?
The user is attempting to come up with a new local planner and needs to integrate it with a global planner for better bench marking.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359258/%5Bnavigation%5D-is-there-a-ros-framework-to-integrate-arbitrary-local-and-global-planners?/) by [NithishkumarS](https://answers.ros.org/users/57632/nithishkumars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what "a lot of hassles" means exactly, but perhaps [move_base_flex](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base_flex) (in ROS 1):

> Move Base Flex (MBF) is a backwards-compatible replacement for move_base. MBF can use existing plugins for move_base, and provides an enhanced version of the planner, controller and recovery plugin ROS interfaces. It exposes action servers for planning, controlling and recovering, providing detailed information of the current state and the plugin’s feedback. An external executive logic can use MBF and its actions to perform smart and flexible navigation strategies.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-12**:
In ROS 2, Navigation 2 is pretty flexible as well and has some of the same design as `move_base_flex`, but it all depends a bit on what "a lot of hassles" means.

**Comment by [NithishkumarS](https://answers.ros.org/users/57632/nithishkumars/) on 2020-08-13**:
Thank you. I understand that plugins is the way to go. By "without a lot of hassles" I guess I wanted to find the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> is there a simple solution to integrate any arbitrary local and global planner in ROS

This is the major rationale for pluginlib plugins. You can just implement a header and be able to load your new algorithm and replace and old one with 1 line of yaml. Not sure it gets much easier than that!

If you’re looking for more flexible solutions to the general navigation problem, MBF or Nav2 are also options but it sounds like you just want to implement a plugin. Implementing plugins will be part of / work with either of those as well.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-08-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1